# Issue reading data into a map

Tags: c++, dictionary

I can't figure out why my pull_data function crashes when it is call I narrowed it down to the "myMap[word]++" lines. However if I understand it correctly it should work. Like if the element with key "word" doesn't exist, the element will be created and value initialized.

My first variation would pull 2 different files and save the data to the 2 different maps with this.

```
if (file.is_open()) {
        while (file >> word) {
            myMap[word]++;
        }
        file.close();
    }
    else {
        cout << "Unable to open file.";
    }
```

But instead of pulling from 2 different files I am trying to make it read one that has all the data I need separated with a | to indicate if i am reading from the on side or the off side.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void pull_data(map<string, float>& myMap1, map<string, float>& myMap2);
void push_data(map<string, float> myMap1, map<string, float> myMap2);
void sync_data(map<string, float>& myMap1, map<string, float>& myMap2);

int main()
{
    map<string, float> offData;
    map<string, float> onData;

    pull_data(offData, onData);

    sync_data(offData, onData);

    push_data(offData, onData);

    system ("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}

void pull_data(map<string, float>& myMap1, map<string, float>& myMap2) {

    string word;
    bool onOff = false;
    ifstream file("Data.txt");

    if (file.is_open()) {
        while (file >> word) {

            if(word == "|" && onOff){
                onOff = false;
            }else if(word == "|"){
                onOff = true;
            }

            if(onOff){
                myMap2[word]++;
            }else{
                myMap1[word]++;
            }

        }
        file.close();
    }
    else {
        cout << "Unable to open file.";
    }
}

void push_data(map<string, float> myMap1, map<string, float> myMap2){}

void sync_data(map<string, float>& myMap1, map<string, float>& myMap2){}
```

Data.txt example

```
362 364 |   112 304 122 124 |
364 304 901 116 |   351 303 112 |
362 364 311 |   351 612 400 484 303 326 |
```

Comment: You are using the operator "++" which should increase the value of data that is returned with the Key [word], but because you may have a null data the operator ++ crach. The Map create and initialize the value with the syntaxis myMap[word] = x (using the operator "=")

Comment: You can't compare strings with ==, instead of you should use std::strcmp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are using a mapped data type that doesn't meet the requirements to be CopyConstructible and DefaultConstructible, `float` is a primitive data type.

That is the reason that you have a Zero reference and it crashed when you are use the operator "++".

Check it:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyConstructible

Comment: So if I am understanding it correctly if i don't use the & and make the function return the maps it will work?

Comment: Ok, @Marzdor, what is the issue? the reason that you program crashed with myMapp[word]++, or another issue?

Comment: One last question, what is the compiler that you are using?

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to get it to work is all.  Since originally it worked with a map using myMapp[word]++ with both int and float as the value and a string for the key but when I started to try and split the data from the file into two different maps it started to crash. Also I am using "TDM-GCC 4.9.2 64-bit Release"

Comment: Do you have some sample of "Data.txt"?

Comment: Ok, I ran your code in VS2015 and Windows 2012r2 and it doesn't crash. So, what  is the error message when it crashed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138265/discussion-between-marzdor-and-jorge-omar-medra).